# AngularJS validating form with submit/cancel buttons

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

I am trying to create a form with submit and cancel butoons, plus validation using AngularJS.

However the validation behaviour is a bit funky. I would prefer validation to be on the viewValue, but at least to be deferred until the submit button is pressed. Currently if the user enters text into a box and blurs without submitting, a validation error will be thrown as the modelValue is still empty.

I hope there is a way to do this without custom directives, or altering the controller. The form is envisioned as part of a nested structure, so it would ideally be self-contained.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Upn3n4XM6GC1o4KigFnl?p=preview

```
<body ng-app="mainModule">
    <div ng-controller="mainController">

        <form name="personForm" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'submit' }" novalidate>
            <md-input-container>
                <label>First name:</label>
                <input id="firstNameEdit" type="text" name="firstName" ng-model="person.firstName" required/>
                <div ng-messages="personForm.firstName.$error" role="alert">
                    <div ng-message="required">You did not enter a first name</div>
                </div>
            </md-input-container>
            <br/>
            <md-input-container>
                <label>Last name:</label>
                <input id="lastNameEdit" type="text" name="lastName" ng-model="person.lastName" required/>
                <div ng-messages="personForm.lastName.$error" role="alert">
                    <div ng-message="required">You did not enter a last name</div>
                </div>
            </md-input-container>
            <br/>
            <md-button type="submit">Save</md-button>
            <md-button ng-click="personForm.$rollbackViewValue();">Cancel</md-button>
            <!-- <ng-include src="'addressForm.html'"></ng-include> -->
        </form>
        <br/>
        <strong>
            <label for="userDebugText">Person:</label>
        </strong><br/>
        <!-- <textarea id="userDebugText">{{person | json}}</textarea><br/> -->
        <pre id="userDebugText">{{person | json}}</pre>
        <br/>
        <strong>
            <label for="firstNameTxt">personForm.firstName:</label>
        </strong><br/>
        <pre id="firstNameTxt">{{personForm.firstName | json}}</pre>
        <strong>
            <label for="lastNameTxt">personForm.lastName:</label>
        </strong><br/>
        <pre id="lastNameTxt">{{personForm.lastName | json}}</pre>
        <strong>
            <label for="lastNameTxt">personForm:</label>
        </strong><br/>
        <pre id="personFormTxt">{{personForm | json}}</pre>

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: your question is not meaningful. please rephrase it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an article that discusses an approach to form validation using a directive.

The usual approach is to prevent form submission until the form is completely valid, which is a bad user experience. This one makes for a better user experience

http://blog.yodersolutions.com/bootstrap-form-validation-done-right-in-angularjs/

Comment: content from the provided URL is no longer available

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example where 'No custom directives' used and only angular in build form validation features in the template and a method in controller. It will help you.

http://plnkr.co/edit/lbiKfYbkZJWSu5oUmsAe?p=preview

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js" data-semver="1.5.8"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <form name="userForm" novalidate>
      <label>
        First Name: <br/>
        <input name="firstname" type="text" ng-model="user.firstName" required><br />
        <span ng-show="userForm.firstname.$error.required && isSubmitted">Please enter First name<br /></span><br />
      </label>
      <label>
        Last Name: <br/>
        <input name="lastname" type="text" ng-model="user.lastName" required><br />
        <span ng-show="userForm.lastname.$error.required && isSubmitted">Please enter Last name<br /></span><br />
      </label>
      <button ng-click="submitUser()">Submit</button>&nbsp;<button>Cancel</button>
    </form>
    <pre>{{ user|json }}</pre>
  </body>

</html>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.isSubmitted = false;
  $scope.submitUser = function() {
    $scope.isSubmitted = true;
  };
});
```